# Redirecting subdomain from http to external https but avoiding redirect alert

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I am using a hosted wiki service which runs over SSL, I have a CNAME redirect from my subdomain to it but browsers show a message saying it is being redirected.

Is there a way I can get around this? My host and the hosted site's tech are disagreeing on what to do (basically each is saying the other needs to do something)

The current set up is:

http://wiki.mydomain.org --> https://mydomain.externalhost.org

Any and all suggestions would be very much appreciated :)

***edit***

The server that my domain on is running Apache, I'm not sure about the external hosts (sorry I'm not so clued up technically as to versions etc)

Within my DNS panel it states: This CNAME record will point wiki.appsforgood.org to appsforgood.onconfluence.com.

I should explain I proposed installing a SSL cert on the wiki sub-domain but my hosts said this wouldn't stop the error message and it should installed at the external hosts server. Of course the external hosts say it needs to be installed on the wiki sub-domain leaving me banging my head on the table trying to get a definitive answer

Comment: Please add some informations about used webserver. Also this seems to be a serverfault question.

Comment: If, when you type `http://wiki.mydomain.com` in your browser, you get redirected to `https://mydomain.externalhost.com`, you're probably not using a CNAME (DNS) alias from `wiki.mydomain.com` to `mydomain.externalhost.com`. Instead, it looks like there's a website at `wiki.mydomain.com` that performs an HTTP redirection (e.g. 302) to the other site (that would be necessary to change from `http://` to `https://` as well).

Answer (score 1):

You are using a CNAME. The problem is that the SSL Certificate is issued for the domain name you're CNAME is pointing to.

To explain where the "problem" is:

1. Someone types into their browser wiki.example.com.
2. The browser gets the IP address of that domain name (jumping through the CNAME, but the browser knows nothing of the CNAME, DNS does this behind the scenes, the browser just gets the IP back) and connects.
3. The browser and server it connects to start the SSL negotiation process. The SSL Certificates says "Hi, I'm example.externalhost.com"
4. The browser see that the server is using a different name than what the user typed in. Throws warning.

What you want is a server to pickup the wiki.example.com and do a Redirect (CNAMEs are NOT redirects). The redirecting server would say "Hi, I'm wiki.example.com; you need to go connect to example.externalhost.com". A browser would see the initial matching name, so no warning, then proceed to connect to the new host (which would also match the name, so no warning).

Comment: Thanks Chris, forgive my ignorance but what would be the easiest way to accomplish that? I dread trying to ask my host in case they send me off on a wild goose chase

Comment: I'm not sure what solution you've got running. Host providers will usually let you **setup a virtual host for the wiki.example.com site, then setup a 301 Redirect on that**. If you call your provider and tell them that, they'll know exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks Chris,  I'll throw that at them and see how helpful they are :)

Comment: I suspect both CNAME and a redirect are currently in action in the OP's problem. He's typing `http://wiki.mydomain.org`, not `https://`. While the CNAME will effectively resolve `wiki.mydomain.org` to `mydomain.externalhost.org`, it won't change the protocol. It's likely that there is (a) a CNAME from `wiki.mydomain.org` to `mydomain.externalhost.org` and an HTTP redirect from `http://wiki.mydomain.org` (or the default server on that IP address if it's not configured for that particular host) to `https://mydomain.externalhost.org`. The certificate needs to match the target host name.

Comment: @Chris S, your description of the problem would be right for a certificate that doesn't match the host name in the URL. However, this didn't seem to be the OP's problem, rather it seems to be about "a message saying it is being redirected", which would almost certainly come from some HTTP-based redirect before any HTTPS connection, and this doesn't seem to be a certificate warning message.

Comment: @Bruno, you're comment would be helpful except I actually tried his URL myself and the warning message is indeed for mismatched certificate. The redirect on the external host only changes the protocol, not the hostname; which you might have known if you had tried the url in the Question.

Comment: @Chris S, sorry I hadn't tried the actual address (my initial comment was before the question was edited). You're right, the OP's description of the problem isn't. (And I agree on CNAMEs not being redirects.)